# Delete next two characters in string with indexOf and map

Tags: java, string, unicode

i have a problem with a algorithm.
I have a Map (Each key int its a hex unicode character) and a String with unicode characters.
I want to delete the next character in the string when i found a character that exists as key in my map.

for example my map contains those keys: `0x111,0x333,0x444,0x555,0x666` and my string its:

```
0x111+0xffff+0x444+0xEEEEE+0x666
```

I want to convert it to:

0x111+0x444+0x666

I have this but this doesnt work:

```
private String cleanFlags(String text) {
        int textLong = text.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < textLong; i++) {
            if (flagCountryEmojis.containsKey(text.codePointAt(text.charAt(i)))) {
                text = text.replace(text.substring(i + 1, i + 2), "");
                textLong-=2;
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
```

How can i do it this?

Comment: Im missing something i cannot quite understand what you want to do. Do you want the alternate keys to me removed ?

Comment: What doesn't work? (beyond the array index out of bounds exception you're probably getting for trying to access the (i+1)'s character, which may not exist).

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mention anything about space complexity, I went ahead and took the liberties of using an array to solve the question:

```
public String cleanFlags(String text){

   String [] arr = text.split("+");
   String newText = "";

   for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       if(flagCountryEmojis.containsKey(arr[i])){
           newText += arr[i];
           i++; // skips the next character
       }
       if(i < arr.length - 1)
           newText += "+";
   }
   return newText;
}
```

Not sure if this solution solves your problem, since strings are immutable anyways, and calling "replace" simply creates a new string in the background, I went ahead and created a new string for you and returned the result when it is populated correctly.

Lemme know if there is something I am missing or other restrictions that were unmentioned.